# Limit of integral of $\frac{2nx^{n-1}}{1+x},\, x\in [0,1]$

Tags: integration, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

For $n = 1, 2, ...., $ let $$f_n(x)= \frac{2nx^{n-1}}{1+x},\, x\in [0,1] .$$

Find $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \limits_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx ?$$

The sequence is not uiform convergent on $[0,1]$, because limit does not exist at $1$. How to approach further for the problem. Is dominated convergence theorem applicable?

Comment: By integration by parts, you have to study $1+2\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying integration by parts with $u=\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $dv=nx^{n-1}$ yields
$$2\frac{x^n}{1+x}|^1_0+2\int \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
The limit of the first part is clear, and the second part is much more well-behaved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.